# How to select multiple columns where one column has duplicate values, without grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to return all data for rows where one particular field in the row is the same for each record, but I can't use `group by` because I need to see all the duplicated records; I don't just want a count of them.

I've tried using `group by` and `having count(field) > 1` and various forms of simple `select` and other ways of trying to use `count()` with no luck.

There are additional `where` requirements, but for simplicity I'm not including them here. I'm using SSMS 2008 R2.

**Example:**

Data:

```
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3
----------------------
abc      wow      13/05/2016
abc      wow      10/05/2016
def      wow      13/05/2016
ghi      wow      13/05/2016
ghi      wow      10/05/2016
jkl      wow      01/01/2016
```

Expected result:

```
Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3
----------------------
abc      wow      13/05/2016
abc      wow      10/05/2016
ghi      wow      13/05/2016
ghi      wow      10/05/2016
```

I am looking to show anything that does not have a unique value in Col1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM (
  SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1) AS cnt
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```

The query uses window version of `COUNT` aggregate function: the function is applied over `Col1` partitions. The outer query filters out records which have a `Col1` value that appears only once.

Comment: Still relevant over 7 years later.  Thank you, Giorgos.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very clear what you are trying to do but maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
with MyDupes as
(
    Select MyColumnWithDupes
        , COUNT(*) as RowCount
    from SomeTable
    Group by MyColumnWithDupes
)

select *
from SomeTable st
join MyDupes md on md.MyColumnWithDupes = st.MyColumnWithDupes
where md.RowCount > 1
```